# The mirror of a rigid Calabi-Yau manifold

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, calabi-yau, mirror-symmetry

In various papers, I have seen descriptions that a rigid Calabi-Yau manifold has its mirror as a Landau-Ginzburg model.
Why do experts think this way?

Any comment welcome !
Thank you.

Edit: In particular, I want to understand why the $\mathcal{Z}$-manifold has its mirror as a cubic sevenfold (which is mentioned in "Generalized Calabi-Yau manifolds and the mirror of a rigid manifold" by Candelas et al).

Answer (score 2):

One paper suggesting this is [1] where Edward Witten showed that we can use supersymmetric linear gauged sigma models to construct theories that lead, depending on the choice of the so-called FI-parameter, to theories that have a vacuum moduli space corresponding to on the one hand to Calabi-Yau manifolds and on the other Landau-Ginzburg models (depending on the sign of the parameter). As such we get a (connected) space of theories uniting both of theses types. Thus using a physical argument we find that these two different types of theories are not independent but rather can be thought of as two different phases in some sense. Interpreting this FI-parameter (and its relation to the Chern classes of the underlying manifold) one can argue that these indeed form mirrors. This is explored (in a lot of detail) in [2].

[1] E.Witten: Phases of n=2 theories in two dimensions (1993)

[2] C.Vafa K.Hori: Mirror Symmetry

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can we see unified methods to  construct mirrors from rigid Calabi-Yau manifolds in these papers ? Or can we find those in any other papers ?

Comment: That I'm not sure of. Out of the two references I gave the second is where you could maybe find something like this though I haven't read the whole book so no idea if it is actually in there. There are definitely methods for certain types of CY manifolds however I do not know these in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have seen a description that the Z manifold (which is a quotient of three tori by Z/3Z) has its mirror as a cubic sevenfold in " Generalized Calabi -Yau manifolds and the mirror of a rigid manifold" by Candelas et al.  For this, is there any reasons why such mirror is obtained (i.e. how to construct it)?